# Which one is the best option to store a pdf file (iBooks or iPhone)

Tags: ios, iphone, pdf

I have a requirement to download a pdf file from my app and to store it either in iBooks or in iPhone. I don't know which one is the best approach. Could someone please suggest the best option and also I need to open it to the user.

Comment: Storing in phone will work even if user don't have iBook App.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in iPhone and then display it in `UIWebView` if you wan to display in application.